# Read only filesystem populated on demand

Tags: filesystems, nfs, sshfs, fuse, network-filesystem

Basically I have a file system that is accessible both by NFS and ssh. I need a copy of this on my local. But I want to pull only those files that I need (basically cache them on demand). Since I'll be using this as a read-only fs the cache is equivalent to a permanent copy (even the remote won't change). So, is there an application that does this out of the box or should I be writing my own FUSE implementation for this? The problem is the FUSE implementation would be for Mac (although I have a Linux container running which can do this too.)

Answer (score 1):

Mount the NFS share.

If desired, read only. Either server side for the export, or locally with the `rdonly` mount option.

Only transferring files on demand is inherent for NFS, you have to open a file to get its contents. Caching, both client and server side, keeps subsequent accesses fast. If for some reason you wish to pre-warm cache, just read the files.

If not NFS, syncing the entire volume to local would be simple. Remote is not changing. But not meet the requirement of only have a local copy on demand.

NFS has the advantage of already being implemented. As file system for macOS or Linux, and as a file share in your environment already. See how it performs before trying the (in my opinion, premature) optimization of writing your own caching file system.

Comment: But I wat it to be populated on demand too. It should very similar to a cache system. Except that the cache is big enough to store the full copy and there will be no need for a cache update ever.

Comment: NFS has in memory caching, and is already implemented. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of relevant files is not too big then you could configure inotify for those files. After a file has been written (and the file descriptor has been closed) you can start `rsync` for that file.

Comment: they are of the order 67k

Comment: @SamarthS That may be too much. But you can reduce the necessary resources by watching only the directories: `inotifywait -m -r root_watch_dir/` That output can be piped to a program that checks whether the respective file is on your list and calls `rsync` in that case.